# Write SQL Query to get Expected Output

Tags: sql, sql-server

i'm trying to get this expected output but its not getting for me...
this is my sql query i don't understand how to get only Those ID whose belongs to `100000006`

[image]

```
select * from friendlist 
         where userid = '100000006' or frienduserid='100000006' and frndstatuid='4'
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Those ID whose belongs to 100000006"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT userid
FROM friendlist
WHERE frienduserid='100000006' AND frndstatuid='4'
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT frienduserid
FROM friendlist
WHERE userid='100000006' AND frndstatuid='4'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from friendlist 
         where (userid = '100000006' or frienduserid='100000006') and frndstatuid='4'
```